# How to search '/>' with sed

Tags: linux, sed

My need is to append a new string after the first `/>` for all files in a directory.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find ./ -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' myfile; do
    sed -i '0,/\/>/asome text here' $myfile
done
```

However, it seems that all of `\n` are matched too. For example if a file is like this:

```
abc
def
<abc/>
<abc/>
```

After executing my script, I'll get the result as below:

```
abc
some text here
def
some text here
<abc/>
some text here
<abc/>
```

It does append the new string for the first occurrence of `/>`, but it appends the new string for each line before the first `/>` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The expression `0,/regex/` will cause the command following it (`a`) to be applied to *all lines* up to (and including) the first match of the regular expression.

My guess is that you instead would want to do

```
sed -i '0,/regex/{//a text
}' "$myfile"
```

This will select all lines up to the first match of the regular expression, and then apply the command only on the line within that range that matches the expression, while passing all other lines through unchanged.

The literal newline is needed to signal the end of the text that you add.

Comment: Note that you don't have to repeat the regex: `sed -i '0,/regex/{//a text ...` will work as well